# How to create a Binary Tree using a String array?

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

I am given an assignment where I need to do the following:

- input your binary tree as an array, using the array representation and node labels A, ..., J, as Strings. Label null stands for a non-existent node, not for a node having a value of null.
- Check the validity of your binary tree input: each node, excepting the root, should have a father.
- Generate the dynamic memory implementation of the tree, using only the nodes with labels different than null.

So far I have:

```
public class Project1{ 
 public static void main(String[] args){
  String[] input = new String[]{"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"};  
 }
  public class BinaryTree<T> implements java.io.Serializable{
   private T data;
    private BinaryTree<T> left;
    private BinaryTree<T> right;
    
    public BinaryTree(T data){
        this.data = data; 
        left = null; 
        right = null;
    }
    public T getData(){
        return data;
    }
    public void attachLeft(BinaryTree<T> tree){
        if(tree != null){
            left = tree;
        }   
    }
    public void attachRight(BinaryTree<T> tree){
        if(tree != null){
            right = tree;
        }   
    }
    public BinaryTree<T> detachLeft(){
      BinaryTree<T> t = left;
      left = null;
      return t;
    }
    public BinaryTree<T> detachRight(){
      BinaryTree<T> t = right;
      right = null;
      return t;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return data == null;
    }
    public void inOrder(BinaryTree<T> tree){
        if (tree != null){
            inOrder(tree.left);
            System.out.println(tree.getData());
            inOrder(tree.right);
        }
    }
    public void preOrder(BinaryTree<T> tree){
        if(tree != null){
            System.out.println(tree.getData());
            preOrder(tree.left);
            preOrder(tree.right);
        }
    }
    public void postOrder(BinaryTree<T> tree){
        if(tree != null){
            postOrder(tree.left);
            postOrder(tree.right);
            System.out.println(tree.getData());
        
        }
    }
    }
```

**What I don't understand is how to create a BinaryTree using my data from the string array**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: "how to create a BinaryTree using my data " is as good as asking "help me complete my assignment". So it would be great if you can add what have you tried so far and what problems your are facing with it

Comment: @shridharRKulkarni I didn't include what I tried because it did not work. Mostly I was just grasping at straws. I am not asking for my whole assignment, I am just trying to get over the hump of getting my data into the BinaryTree class. I know how I would create an iterative solution to get my data into a BinaryTree, I just have no clue how to create an object of BinaryTree at this time.